# Invisibility Effect (Dual-Video Overlay)

Tags: modifiers, shaders, video-sequence-editor, video, masking

gif: https://i.stack.imgur.com/frSde.jpg (excerpt from https://vimeo.com/101172118)

Wondering if this is possible in Blender. Is it masking and chromakeying? Not really sure what to call it: two moving images overlayed, the one on top essentially transparent but affecting the bottom video? Should i use a glass shader or is there a better way? (Hoping to not have to learn after effects)

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: does it help this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SO9GuS3CP-U

Comment: or this: https://cgjam.net/invisibility-effect/

Comment: interesting, rotoscope and displacement map!